All solutions to Ax=b
I refer to the worked example 3.4 B (case 2) in the book Introduction to Linear Algebra (4ed) by Gilbert Strang.  One of the questions is that if all solutions to $Ax=b$ have the form
$$
x=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
what does that tell us about $b$.  The official solution mentions

column 2 (of $A$) is the negative of column 1

which I can understand; and

$b=2$ (column 1) + (column 2)

which is true but I believe this is an under-statement!  The reason is that
$$
Ax=
\begin{bmatrix}
u&-u\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 + c\\
1 + c\\
\end{bmatrix}=u=b
$$
This implies $b$ is exactly equal to the first column of $A$.  Am I correct?

If you want us to take a look at your problem, please put the entire statement, what is $A$ and what is $B$. Also you probably have $\ker A  = k \begin{pmatrix} 1 \ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix} 2\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a particular solution, then the set of solutions is exactly $v + \ker A$, which is what the book states. This is not an understatement.

There is no $B$ in the question, and $A$ is not specified.
The entire statement copied:
"3.4 B If you have this information about the solutions to $Ax=b$ for a specific $b$, what does that tell you about the shape of $A$ (and $A$ itself)?  And possibly about $b$.
...
2. All solutions to $Ax=b$ have the form
$$
x=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\
1\
\end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}
1\
1\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
"

Ok thanks so the conclusion you have is $A = \begin{pmatrix}b & -b\end{pmatrix}$? Yes this is correct

Let us denote the two columns of $A$ by $C_1$ and $C_2$.
Given that $A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}=0$ i.e. $$C_2=-C_1,$$
the second information,
$A\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}=b$ i.e. $$2C_1+C_2=b,$$ is equivalent to $$C_1=b.$$ So, you are not correct in your belief that it is an "understatement".

Right, so $b$ is indeed equal to the first column of $A$.  Thanks.
